# LINQ with Lambda expression - Left Join ,GroupBy ,Count

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

Necesito pasar esta expresión **lambda** para ser usada en `c#`, 
la uso para saber el número de chats por agentes

```
SELECT
    aa.UserId agent,
    COUNT (c.Id) chatsPerAgent
FROM
    AvailableAgents aa
LEFT OUTER JOIN Chat c ON aa.UserId = c.AgentId
WHERE
    aa.IsAvailable = 1
GROUP BY
    aa.UserId
```

y obtener algo así donde la primera columna es el **id** del agente y 
la segunda el número de chats que esta atendiendo

```
3fde3b78-815a-4c6a-b03c-a2b473ed12d2    3
74ac56eb-b8d6-44d3-914a-8af6386b00e6    0
a2d31e31-7052-445a-94d5-0af47f751c15    2
daeafdb2-52de-4126-a2eb-498346f3d1nh    0
```

empece con esto

```
var items = corporateCHATcontext.AvailableAgents
            .Join(corporateCHATcontext.Chat, cr => cr.UserId, bn => bn.AgentId, (cr, bn) => new { cr, bn })
            .Where( x=> x.cr.IsAvailable==true && x.bn.IdState==2 && x.bn.FinishDate==null && x.bn.Date >= today && x.bn.Date <= midnight)
            .GroupBy(x => new { x.bn.AgentId })
            .Select(g => new {
                g.Key.AgentId,
                Count = g.Count()
            })
            .ToList();
```

pero solo me devuelve

```
3fde3b78-815a-4c6a-b03c-a2b473ed12d2    3
a2d31e31-7052-445a-94d5-0af47f751c15    2
```

Comment: ¿Como vas con tu expresión? ¿Que es lo que estás haciendo en c#? Muestranos para poder apoyar sobre tu ejemplo.

Comment: no se como hacer el join con los valores en 0

Comment: checa este link, en la segunda respuesta. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700523/linq-to-sql-left-outer-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para este tipo de casos me ha funcionado [GroupJoin()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupjoin?view=netframework-4.8) debido a que mantiene el grupo relacionado desde que asignas como si fuera el mismo Join(); y a su vez puedes controlar los registros null con [DefaultIfEmpty()](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.defaultifempty?view=netframework-4.8). Ya sobre esto puedes trabajar tus resultados a como los necesites.

```
var itmes = corporateCHATcontext.AvailableAgents.GroupJoin(
    corporateCHATcontext.Chat,
    cr => cr.UserId, 
    bn => bn.AgentId, 
    (cr, bn) => new { cr, bn })
    .SelectMany( x => x.bn.DefaultIfEmpty(),
         (x,y) => new { cr=x.cr, bn=y})
   .Where( x=> x.cr.IsAvailable==true && x.bn.IdState==2 && x.bn.FinishDate==null && x.bn.Date >= today && x.bn.Date <= midnight).GroupBy(x => new { x.bn.AgentId })
            .Select(g => new {
                g.Key.AgentId,
                Count = g.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

Básicamente, primero arma tu full join correctament; que ya tienes, [controla tus registros null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/584840/4068497), que representa el right join que no existe, y sobre estos iEnumerables trabaja tus contadores, registros, etc.